# levelplot index issue

Tags: raster, r

`levelplot` with static index works fine but not in a for loop. What's wrong with my code?

Static index:

```
png(paste("1998",outlist[[1]],".png",sep=""))
levelplot(RAD1998.all[[1:4]])
dev.off()

png(paste("1998",outlist[[5]],".png",sep=""))
levelplot(RAD1998.all[[5:8]])
dev.off()

png(paste("1998",outlist[[9]],".png",sep=""))
levelplot(RAD1998.all[[9:12]])
dev.off()
```

For loop:

```
for(i in seq(from=1, to=length(list.ras), by=4)) {
    png(paste("1998_",outlist[[i]],".png",sep=""))
    levelplot(RAD1998.all[[i:i+3]])
    dev.off()
}
```

Comment: Use `subset`. `levelplot(subset(RAD1998.all, i:[i+3]))`. And be careful, `i:i+3` is not doing what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

You can try the following:

```
for(i in seq(from=1, to=length(list.ras), by=4)){
 Obj <- levelplot(subset(RAD1998.all, i:(i+3)))
 png(paste("1998_",outlist[[i]],".png",sep=""))
 print(Obj) 
 dev.off()
}
```

Comment: And be careful, i:i+3 is not doing what you think. --> True I have blank white image files. I checked subset with static  and index cases and both of them didn't plot. So subset is key to solve problem but Static:                                   png(paste("LP",outlist[[13]],".png",sep=""))
levelplot(subset(RAD1998.all[[13:24]]))
dev.off()           Index                                                   index = length(list.ras)
for(i in seq(from=1, to=index, by=12)){
      png(paste("Level_",outlist[[i]],".png",sep=""))
 levelplot(subset(RAD1998.all[[i:i+11]]))
 dev.off()

}

Comment: Once again, [[i:i+11]] is not doing what you think. Did you check the result of `i=1; i:i+11`? And you are not using `subset` as it should be used. Why don't you follow the example I posted?

Comment: [R FAQ 7.22 Why do lattice/trellis graphics not work?](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f): Lattice functions such as `xyplot()` (and `levelplot()`) create a graph object, but do not display it. The `print()` method for the graph object produces the actual display. When you use these functions interactively at the command line, the result is automatically printed, but in `source()` or inside your own functions you will need an explicit `print()` statement.

Comment: print works but it has one image

Comment: I am studying, http://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/ and example you posted didn't work

Comment: Code edited. It should work now.

Comment: Error: unexpected '[' in:
"
levelplot(subset(RAD1998.all,i:["

Comment: Yes, please use the edited code.

Comment: Yes, it worked !!! Than you so much!!!

Comment: Instead of `subset` you can also use the `layers` argument in `levelplot`.